# Certificate verification worries

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl, java, x.509

I am having trouble getting a SSL connection to work. I did a lot of research on the web, but i am still missing some understanding it seems. I hope you can help me. I generate a development certificate chain:
RootCA -> SubCA -> Server

I generate them like this

```
openssl req -batch -x509 -config ${ROOTCA_CONFIG} -newkey rsa:2048 -sha1 -nodes -out ${ROOTCA_CERT} -outform PEM -days 7300 
openssl req -batch -config ${SUBCA_CONFIG} -newkey rsa:2048 -sha1 -nodes -out ${SUBCA_CSR} -outform PEM
openssl ca -batch -config ${ROOTCA_CONFIG} -policy signing_policy -extensions signing_req_CA -out ${SUBCA_CERT} -infiles ${SUBCA_CSR}
```

I then add the RootCA certificate to my Java trust store and the client certificate to the key store. 
That is the first thing that puzzles me: The SubCA Cert has the plaintext information i expect. The Root CA only has cryptographic information (the part between BEGIN and END CERTIFICATE. Is this to be exptected?
My SubCA Cert looks like this, i truncated the crypto part:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1 (0x1)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=DE, O=Company, CN=Root CA 2016
        Validity
            Not Before: Oct 20 11:59:57 2016 GMT
            Not After : Oct 18 11:59:57 2024 GMT
        Subject: C=DE, O=Company, CN=SubCA 2016
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:ae:0b:94:36:76:7c:34:d8:37:61:44:5f:1c:68:
                    ...                        

                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                43:2E:0E:EB:66:C6:2F:AC:1B:24:C7:95:48:92:95:6E:E3:E0:83:1E
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:19:6B:27:27:F8:9F:56:E3:07:E7:AB:51:1E:15:DC:F8:F1:96:D5:35

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl.url

            Authority Information Access: 
                CA Issuers - URI:http://downloads.some.url
```

I then create a server certificate (variable names call it client, since it is used for generating both):

```
openssl req -batch -config ${CLIENT_CONFIG} -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -out ${CLIENT_CSR} -outform PEM -keyout $1.key
openssl ca -batch -config ${SUBCA_CONFIG} -policy signing_policy -extensions signing_req -out ${CLIENT_CERT} -infiles ${CLIENT_CSR}
```

The server cert looks like this:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1 (0x1)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=DE, O=Company, CN=SubCA 2016
        Validity
            Not Before: Oct 20 12:18:18 2016 GMT
            Not After : Oct 20 12:18:18 2018 GMT
        Subject: C=DE, ST=Bayern, L=Mytown, O=Company, OU=OU, CN=My Server
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    ...
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                53:C6:01:AB:E4:AA:C4:A4:BC:8B:2D:45:9C:92:40:5D:59:B7:AD:A0
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:43:2E:0E:EB:66:C6:2F:AC:1B:24:C7:95:48:92:95:6E:E3:E0:83:1E

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl.url.de/some.crl

            Authority Information Access: 
                CA Issuers - URI:http://some.url.de/rootcacert2016.cert

            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:localhost, DNS:127.0.0.1, DNS:some.url.de
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         ...
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Now i would like to verify the generated certificate. This fails with the message

> error 2 at 1 depth lookup:unable to get issuer certificate

If verifies correctly if i concatenate SubCA and CA file into a single file. Is this also correct? I expected the certificate to be verifiable with each certificate?

And now to my problem: When i try to connect to my service, it provides its server certificate. I checked it with wireshark, to be sure. The client then fails authenticating with the message

> “unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

I exported the server certificate as PKCS12 token and imported it into my java keystore. Im imported the ca/subca certificates into my truststore. This is presented by the server as expected. So i guess i messed up the certificate chain somehow. Since the concatenated certficate files worked so nicely with openssl, i tried to import that into my truststore. This leads to only have the subca certificate, so i guess this does now work. When i import both individually, the certificate list is fine. However, the certification path somehow is not right. Can you give me a hand? I am getting a bit frustrated...

Update: 
This is the root certificate:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 13418448032209606381 (0xba37e7642ce496ed)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=DE, O=Company, CN=IDS Root CA 2016
        Validity
            Not Before: Oct 20 11:59:57 2016 GMT
            Not After : Oct 15 11:59:57 2036 GMT
        Subject: C=DE, O=Fraunhofer, CN=IDS Root CA 2016
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                   ...
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                19:6B:27:27:F8:9F:56:E3:07:E7:AB:51:1E:15:DC:F8:F1:96:D5:35
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:19:6B:27:27:F8:9F:56:E3:07:E7:AB:51:1E:15:DC:F8:F1:96:D5:35

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Non Repudiation, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         ...
```

This is my config file to create the server cert:

```
HOME            = .
RANDFILE        = $ENV::HOME/.rnd

####################################################################
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
#default_keyfile     = connector.key
distinguished_name  = connector_distinguished_name
req_extensions      = connector_req_extensions
string_mask         = utf8only

####################################################################
[ connector_distinguished_name ]
countryName         = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default     = DE

stateOrProvinceName     = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = Bayern

localityName            = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default        = Muenchen

organizationName         = Organization Name (eg, company)
organizationName_default    = Company

organizationalUnitName  = Organizational Unit Name (department, division)
organizationalUnitName_default  = OU

commonName          = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_default      = Test Server

emailAddress            = Email Address
emailAddress_default        = test@mail.com


####################################################################
[ connector_req_extensions ]

subjectKeyIdentifier        = hash
basicConstraints        = CA:FALSE
keyUsage            = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment, nonRepudiation
extendedKeyUsage    = clientAuth
#securityProfile = ASN1:UTF8:IDS Security Profile Specification
#subjectAltName         = URI:UUID:%%DEVICE_UUID%%
subjectAltName          = @alternate_names

[ alternate_names ]

DNS.1       = localhost
DNS.2       = 127.0.0.1
DNS.3       = some.url.com
```

Comment: we can't see your server certificate. `If verifies correctly if i concatenate SubCA and CA file into a single file. Is this also correct?` -- nope. this indicates that your AIA extension is incorrect and issuer certificate is not available at specified URL.

Comment: Ah, sorry, i pasted the SubCA cert twice. Now the server cert is there. Thanks!

Comment: According to your config file, server certificate is missing `Authority Information Access` extension with URLs to locate issuer certificate.

Comment: These are just test certificates for development. I do not have a server providing these certificates. They are loaded into the java trust store on the client side. Should this not be sufficient?

Comment: Then you must bundle all certificates in the chain into a single file.

Comment: This works for openssl. I can cat rootca subca > cachain and verify with that. I use Java to build my TLS connection, however and when i add both certificates to the client's trust store, i get the mentioned error message. So something must be wrong, i guess...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution. I only set debugging to SSL. This was my mistake. I would have needed to set the debug output to "all". Then i can see this error message:

> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: Extended key
>   usage does not permit use for TLS server authentication

This is much more specific. To fix that, indeed i needed to change my extended key usage to this:

```
keyUsage            = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment, nonRepudiation
extendedKeyUsage    = clientAuth, serverAuth
```

Thank you very much!